# How to get response data from google-chat webhook?

Tags: node.js, gunzip, google-chat

I'm following the following example:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const webhookURL = '<INCOMING-WEBHOOK-URL>';

const data = JSON.stringify({
  'text': 'Hello from a Node script!',
});

fetch(webhookURL, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: data,
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

For all intents and purposes, my code is essentially the same.

According to API response body should be of type Message but instead I'm getting the following:

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: Gunzip {
      _writeState: [Uint32Array],
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      bytesWritten: 0,
      _handle: [Zlib],
      _outBuffer: <Buffer 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 00 48 02 15 01 00 00 00 05 00 04 00 04 00 04 00 38 2f 01 15 01 00 00 00 30 46 01 15 01 00 00 00 1e 1e ... 16334 more bytes>,
      _outOffset: 0,
      _chunkSize: 16384,
      _defaultFlushFlag: 2,
      _finishFlushFlag: 2,
      _defaultFullFlushFlag: 3,
      _info: undefined,
      _maxOutputLength: 4294967295,
      _level: -1,
      _strategy: 0,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kTransformState)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kError)]: null
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: <my webhook url>,
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to process this data to read it as the desired Message type, as referenced in the API docs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For reference: https://developers.google.com/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces/webhooks

Comment: have you tried putting `async` before the function call?

Comment: Yes, actually my second thought was to try doing `const response = await fetch(...)`. The response object is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was remarkably simple.
I forgot that in order to read the contents of `fetch` as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) I need to call

```
const resJson = await response.json()
```